# Admin logout is not working properly after override of adminhtml controller

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, overrides

I had override admin user controller, it was working fine but when I click on logout link page is not redirecting to admin login page.page is redirecting on front side.

Front screen shot http://postimg.org/image/71bshl9ar/

Override code.

```
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <FME_Bookingreservation before="Mage_Adminhtml">FME_Bookingreservation</FME_Bookingreservation>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Controller code:

```
    require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php';
class FME_Bookingreservation_Permissions_UserController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Permissions_UserController
{


public function saveAction()
{

    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {


       $data['workshop_id'] = implode(',', $data['workshop_id']);

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id');
        $model = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($id);
        if (!$model->getId() && $id) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('This user no longer exists.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
        $model->setData($data);

        /*
         * Unsetting new password and password confirmation if they are blank
         */
        if ($model->hasNewPassword() && $model->getNewPassword() === '') {
            $model->unsNewPassword();
        }
        if ($model->hasPasswordConfirmation() && $model->getPasswordConfirmation() === '') {
            $model->unsPasswordConfirmation();
        }

        $result = $model->validate();
        if (is_array($result)) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setUserData($data);
            foreach ($result as $message) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('_current' => true));
            return $this;
        }

        try {
            $model->save();
            $workshop_collection = Mage::getModel('bookingreservation/staffmembers')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('workshop_admin_user_id',$model->getUserId());
         foreach($workshop_collection as $collection)
         {
            $workshop = Mage::getModel('bookingreservation/staffmembers')->load($collection->getStaffmembers_id());
            $workshop->setWorkshopAdminUserId(1);
            $workshop->save();                 
         }
         foreach($this->getRequest()->getPost('workshop_id') as $w_id)
         {
               $workshop = Mage::getModel('bookingreservation/staffmembers')->load($w_id);
               $workshop->setWorkshopAdminUserId($model->getUserId());
               $workshop->save();
         }

            if ( $uRoles = $this->getRequest()->getParam('roles', false) ) {
                /*parse_str($uRoles, $uRoles);
                $uRoles = array_keys($uRoles);*/
                if ( 1 == sizeof($uRoles) ) {
                    $model->setRoleIds($uRoles)
                        ->setRoleUserId($model->getUserId())
                        ->saveRelations();
                } else if ( sizeof($uRoles) > 1 ) {
                    //@FIXME: stupid fix of previous multi-roles logic.
                    //@TODO:  make proper DB upgrade in the future revisions.
                    $rs = array();
                    $rs[0] = $uRoles[0];
                    $model->setRoleIds( $rs )->setRoleUserId( $model->getUserId() )->saveRelations();
                }
            }
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The user has been saved.'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setUserData(false);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setUserData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('user_id' => $model->getUserId()));
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}



}
```

Comment: Can you post the controller code?

Comment: I've added you code to my magento instance. The controller is overwritten (so the module is ok) but I don't get the result you get. I get the expected result: *redirected to login page*. Maybe something else is causing the problem. Or something else in combination with your controller.

Comment: @marius Add controller code

Comment: When I add override code then error occurred so may be I think this is the reason otherwise everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common cause of something like this is the logout URL

```
http://magento.example.com/index.php/admin/index/logout/key/9f874d25529246149a02320fa07aecd1/
```

is matching some other controller and NOT the

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
```

file with the logout logic.  Does your module have an `IndexController` file? If so, remove it, because when you said

```
<FME_Bookingreservation before="Mage_Adminhtml">
```

you told Magento to look in your module for `admin` controllers first.

Comment: Yes module have an indexController file, but it is used for other purpose too so I can override controller with other module thanks